# Moving a view around the screen

Tags: android, rescale

I have an imageview that moves around the screen. So, I've set the LayoutParams to do it. But, the android insists on resize my imageview. How can I prevent this behavior?

```
public void move(int x, int y)
{
    width = this.getWidth();
    height = this.getHeight();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    int t = validateMin(calcTopPos(y));
    int l = validateMin(calcLeftPos(x));
    int r = validateMaxWidth(calcRightPos(x))-1;
    int b = validateMaxHeight(calcBottomPos(y));
    params.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the layout.xml?

Comment: And while you are at it, rename those uppercase local variables to width and height ;)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini is correct, you shouldn't use uppercase for variables that are not final/constants :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer: android:adjustViewBounds = "true" in the xml file. But, I still don't know why android was resizing my view. It's a mystery!